# Generate an array of charts

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I want to generate an array of charts and insert them into the DOM.
(I want to use these charts as templates and insert them at the right time)

```
like that:
Var array = [];
array[0].kendoChart ({// .........});
array[1].kendoChart ({// .........});
array.forEach (function (el) {
$('body').append(el);
})
```

Tell me how to be?

Answer (score 0):

I would keep an array of the data used to generate the charts, and then generate them at the time of insert.

In HTML provide a container for the charts to be inserted (could be body as in your example):

```
<div id="chartsContainer" ></div>
```

Then in script have an array of the data needed to generate the multiple charts, e.g. :

```
var charts = [
    {
      chartid: "id1", title: "Chart 1", 
      data: [{ x: "item1", y: 2}, { x: "item2", y: 4},{ x: "item3", y: 1}]
    },
    {
     chartid: "id2", title: "Chart 2", 
     data: [{ x: "item1", y: 8}, { x: "item2", y: 3},{ x: "item3", y: 7},{ x: "item4", y: 2}]
    },         
    {
     chartid: "id3", title: "Chart 3", 
     data: [{ x: "item1", y: 1}, { x: "item2", y: 2},{ x: "item3", y: 4} ]
    },         
];
```

Finally loop through the array, insert DIVs in the container and create a chart in each DIV:

```
  $("#chartsContainer").empty();
  var arrayLength = charts.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    var div = $('<div id="' + charts[i].chartid + '"></div>');
    $("#chartsContainer").append(div);
    div.kendoChart({
        theme: "Flat",
        chartArea: { height: 200 },
        dataSource: {data: charts[i].data },
        title: { text: charts[i].title},
        seriesDefaults: {type: "column"},
        series: [{field: "y" }],            
        categoryAxis: {
            field: "x",
            majorGridLines: {visible: false },
        }              
    });
  }
```

## Working **[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/URoNo)**